# Windows 2012 Server - Audit Who Logged User Off

Tags: user-accounts, windows-server-2012, event-log, event-viewer

Is there a way to tell who logged a user off with Windows 2012 Server? For example, I use `rdp` to log into a box that as multiple admins, there are some scripts that run under a specific user. The account was signed off this morning, and I need to determine who logged them off. There is the option for other admins to log off users via `Task Manager -> Users Tab -> Right click -> Sign off`.

Googling hasn't helped much on this. I ran Event Viewer and looked through the security subsection of Windows Logs. I'm looking through the details of the logoff category, but don't see a clear way of seeing who issued the log off... am I in the right location, or do I need to be looking somewhere else?

Comment: Have you got the Logoff auditing policies enabled?

Comment: When you have identified which of the events states a logoff of a user you might want to use psloglist (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897544.aspx) to export them (this even works on a remote server)